# $U$ open, in closure of $A$ implies $\overline{A \cap U} $ is dense in $U$

Tags: general-topology

We have $U$ is an open set, and we want to show that $$U \subset \bar{A} \Longleftrightarrow \overline{A \cap U}\cap U = U$$

Here, $\bar{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$.

I was able to show the ($\Leftarrow$) direction. For the ($\Rightarrow$) direction, I was able to show that $U \subset \overline{A \cap U}$. How do I show that $\overline{A \cap U} \subset U$?

Comment: $A=(0,3)$ and $U=(1,2)$. $U\subset \overline{A}$ but $\overline{A\cap U}=\overline{U}\ne U$. Or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: The actual phrasing of the problem is $A \cap U$ is a dense subset of the subspace $U$. Doesn't this mean $\overline{A \cap U} = U$? Or should it be something like $\overline{A \cap U} \cap U = U$ ?

Comment: To be dense in $U$ means that the clousure (in the topology inherited by $U$) is equal $U$: $\overline{A\cap U}^U=U$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron I think that just made my question trivial LOL thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the very useful theorem:  open U implies 
$U \cap \bar A \subseteq \overline {U \cap A}$.
Proof.
Assume x in $U \cap \bar A$.
Thus for all open V nhood x, exists y in V $\cap$ A.
As x in open U $\cap$ V, exists y in V $\cap$ U $\cap$ A.
Hence x in $\overline {U \cap A}$, QED.